# Validate user-entered RegEx in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsregularexpression

I have a predicate editor that allows the user to use "matches" for RegEx, thus they are entering a text string that is a RexEx used to search. If they enter something wrong, I get:

```
Can't open pattern U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX (string /Volumes/[path to certain file].mp4, pattern (*.abc.*)|(*.abd.*), case 1, canon 2)
```

How can I validate the string? If I don't and the user saves the file, it quits when trying to resolve this.

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: Do you use `NSRegularExpression` or `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
@try
{
    NSPredicate* predicate = [[self predicateEditor] objectValue];
    [predicate evaluateWithObject:myObject];
}
@catch (NSException* exception)

    NSLog(@"Attempted to create invalid criteria, probably a bad RegEx");
    error = YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does work. I could have answered your question yesterday if you had answered my question.

Comment: How would I validate correct syntax of a NSRegularExpression?

Comment: I don't know, I use `NSRuleEditor` and had the same problem.